# For dummies approach to build image and run own code on Docker

Tags: docker

I am trying to work with Docker. I want to run a supersimple program on Docker (to get acquainted with Docker).

I have gone through most of Dockers own tutorials, but did work with own code any where so I am left puzzled. When searching online there are a lot of hits (which i have attempted to understand), but most of them either involve more unknown tools (maven, springboot, django) or they are far too complicated.

Say i have a helloworld.py (or helloworld.java). How do i do go about running it on Docker? * by running i mean upload and execute.

Do i need to download java on docker? what sequence of steps are needed? 
I know this is a "stupid" question, which is why i specified a dummies-approach.

Any help will greatly be appreciated. Even links that cover this (which i have not succeded in finding)

Comment: There isn't a _for dummies approach_ to Docker, the documentation is enough to have a complete introduction: https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/. First understand the concept of **image** and **container** and the tools you have to use (build, run, etc).

Comment: I have gone through both "Get started with Docker" and learn by example, but still not managed to grasp how i simply can do what i wish to do. I know the generals that at some point i need to write a dockerfile, that the docker engine has to run and so on. The sequence in which what is done and certain commands that i lack. Any specific section you are refering to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic image for running a "hello world" example in Python:

You have to create these two files in a folder.

*Dockerfile*:

```
FROM python:2

COPY ./helloworld.py /

CMD ["/usr/bin/python", "/helloworld.py"]
```

*helloworld.py*:

```
print "hello world"
```

Look for the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) to understand what `FROM`, `COPY` and `CMD` do.

First you [build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) the container:

```
docker build -t hellopython <path-of-image-folder>
```

Verify that the image is listed:

```
docker images
```

[Run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) a new container:

```
docker run hellopython
```

Use [ps](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) to list the containers:

```
docker ps -a
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i've been looking for.
One question: my approach so far has been abit different. One difference is that you dont have the apt-get for python. How come? This is the one that aborted the image building with me.

Comment: No you don't need to install python with apt. This Dockerfile inherits directly from the official python image, check the official image:  https://hub.docker.com/_/python/. Docker images are built in layers check the documentation for `FROM`.